# Centering things and layouting elements related to each other -- how to do it properly

Tags: html, css

I need to get the following layout on my web page:

[image]

All elements have the fixed height (images as shown on their placeholders, YouTube player -- 640x390) and all these elements should be placed in the center of the document.

The best solution I can think of is the following:

**CSS**

```
.center-both {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
}

 #logo {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

 #player {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 640px;
  max-width: 640px;
  height: 390px;
  max-height: 390px;
}

#copy {
  margin-bottom: 131px;
}

 #next {
  margin-bottom: 131px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="center-both">
  <img id="logo" src="http://placehold.it/246x105">
  <img id="copy" src="http://placehold.it/128x128">
  <iframe id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000"></iframe>
  <img id="next" src="http://placehold.it/128x128">
</div>
```

(JSFiddle gives me the trash result btw -- https://jsfiddle.net/aadzfkmr/)

So:

- `center-both` class is supposed to be used for both vertical and horizontal centering for all my elements on the document
- `#logo` should have `display: block` and `margin: auto` styles to be placed on top of YouTube player instead of left-to.
- `margin-bottom: 131px` is an ugly hack that I use at the moment to vertically align left and right images (390px of the player's height / 2 - 128px of the image's height / 2 = 131px)
- `#player` should have fixed height and width because it transforms to the `iframe` from the `div` element dynamically via JS

It works but I have an ugly flickering when the page loads before all elements take their right places.

Actually it'll be a lot better to have YouTube player in the center of the document despite of the logo above (it can be placed a bit higher then).

What is the best way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not worried about getting it done for Responsive design, then go for this below solution!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.w-896 {
  width: 896px;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.center-both {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.child {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle
}
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.w-128 {
  width: 128px;
}
w-frame {
  width: 640px
}
```

```html
<div class="w-896 text-center">
  <img id="logo" src="http://placehold.it/246x105" class="center-block">
</div>
<div class="center-both w-896">
  <div class="child w-128">
    <img id="copy" src="http://placehold.it/128x128">
  </div>
  <div class="child w-frame">
    <iframe id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="child w-128">
    <img id="next" src="http://placehold.it/128x128">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think there should also be `center-both` class to place all these elements in the center of the document

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
#player {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 640px;
  max-width: 640px;
  height: 390px;
  max-height: 390px;
}

#copy {
  margin-bottom: 131px;
}

 #next {
  margin-bottom: 131px;
}
.center-both {
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
}
#logo {
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:246px;
  height:105px;
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to fix? It breaks the centering of all elements btw

Comment: In Google Chrome and JSFiddle it makes it look exactly as you show it; don't see what it breaks at all...

Comment: Can you provide a link to JSFiddle? It has those ugly `margin-bottom` hacks anyway

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5psgpadg/embedded/result/

Note that you have to work with fixed width for the main container which in this case is minimum 910px

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
#logo {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
#player {
  width: 640px;
  height: 390px;
}
```

Refer this working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antonysuthakarj/eoygLdn7/embedded/result/)

Comment: Left and right images are placed too far away from the player

Comment: The above mentioned solution is one of the approach to get this done. At the same time I am not saying this is the solution. Few more approaches we can try. For full code view please refer the jsfiddle link

Comment: See the updated link    https://jsfiddle.net/antonysuthakarj/eoygLdn7/1/embedded/result/

Comment: Why because the iframe width is set by 'px' in your code. If possible you can use '%' to set width and 'px' for min-width.